# Analytic solution of the following PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Consider the initial value problem:

$u_t-(xu)_x = 0$, $\qquad$  $u(x,0) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}\cos^2(\pi x/2), & -1\leq x \leq 1,\\0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$

---

I have tried separation of variables, but I am stuck on the eigenvalue problem. Assume $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, then$$\begin{array}{l}
X(x)T'(t)-(xX(x)T(t))_x = 0,\\
X(x)T'(t)-T(t)[X(x)+xX'(x)] = 0.
\end{array}$$ Thus assume $$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = \frac{X(x) + xX'(x)}{X(x)} = -\lambda.$$
Hence we have $$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
xX'(x) + (1+\lambda)X(x) = 0, &-1\leq x\leq 1,\\
T'(t)+\lambda T(t) =0, & t>0,\\
X(-1) = 0, \quad X(1)=0.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Whether there is an analytic solution for this PDE? How to calculate it if there exists an analytic solution? Any hints or bibliography will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Separation of variables suggests it self.

Comment: I have tried separation of variables, but I usually using separation of variables in solving the second order PDEs instead of the first order PDEs.

Comment: Use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). I get the general solution as $$u(x,t) = e^{t}f(xe^{t})$$ now apply your initial condition.

Comment: Thank you @mattos !  Method of characteristics works.